# checking concavity with second-order derivative

Tags: calculus

I have a function whose second derivative is given as :

$\frac{-2ab(1-x)}{(c-b(x-1)^2)^2}$ however this can also be written as

$\frac{2ab(x-1)}{(bx^2-2bx+b-c)^2}$

For a function to be concave . its second derivative must be less than 0. but I am not sure whether my function is concave or not .

Comment: my x ranges between 0 and 1 , does it means that solution exists for my x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the denominator, it’s squared so we can disregard it as it will always be positive.

Look at the denominator: it will be positive if $ab(x-1)$  is positive. This means than if $ab$ is positive, and your $x$ ranges from zero to one, your second derivative will be negative.

But if $ab$ is negative, and ranges from zero to one, your second derivative will be positive since negative times negative is positive.

Comment: thankyou for the help.